# How can I trigger an onchange function with a <selected> element>

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript function that needs to be triggered based on a selected option, however I would like for a default to be selected

```
<select class="custom-select" name="" id="timer1numbers" onchange="getSelected1()">
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8" selected>8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

How can I trigger the script without requiring a change from the user?

Answer (score 1):

Just by calling `document.getElementById("timer1numbers").onchange();` this, you can trigger your very first `onchange` event with the selected value.

Here is the code snippet and look at the console:

```js
function getSelected1() {
    var value = document.getElementById("timer1numbers").value;
    console.log(value);
}

document.getElementById("timer1numbers").onchange();
```

```html
<select class="custom-select" name="" id="timer1numbers" onchange="getSelected1()">
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8" selected>8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```